# HTML заданная и фактическая ширина блока различается. PPI

Tags: html, вёрстка

Задал ширину body 1200, заскринил посчитал, по факту 1500.

Есть 2 блока с такими свойствами:

```
section{
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 50px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: silver;
}

aside{
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

если к ширине одного из них прибавить один пиксель то они перестают быть в один ряд значит все правильно с margin.

Я так понимаю это как-то связано с PPI монитора.
Фактические размеры всегда отличются? Это сильно путает.
Может есть способ седалать все пиксель в пиксель?
Или это не нужно и все так верстают?

Comment: Используй `Flex && grid`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сделать положение секций или блоков идеально пиксель в пиксель, то я бы вам посоветовал использовать не пиксельное, а процентное соотношение. Вот пример:

```
section{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: silver;
}

aside{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

Это придаст вашему коду адаптивность, так же вы можете использовать свойство auto. Пример -

```
section{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    background-color: silver;
}

aside{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

Если я не правильно понял суть вопроса, то объясните подробнее.

Comment: width задал 1200, а получил 1500. Сейчас померил отступы, при 2% они равны 30 60 30 (горизонтальные отступы между двумя блоками). 100% ширины равно 1500px, а задавал я 1200. Проверял на фаерфоксе и хроме. Мне интересно почему страница "увеличена"?

Comment: Ну здесь я с вами согласен, это в большинстве своём зависит от PPI монитора, но то-бы узнать все точно, я бы посоветовал вам загуглить.